# Fast Deserialisation or Persisting a List of Custom Objects

Tags: c#, serialization, persistence

I'm working on a program which needs a bunch of precalculated data in order to perform realtime calculations in a satisfactory time for users. I've managed to perform my precalcs and write them out to a Serialized data file (it took over 26 hours of processing). The data written out is simply a List of 812175 custom 'PrePair' objects and the resulting file is 100MB in size.

```
        [Serializable]
        private class PrePairsList_IO
        {

            private List<PrePair> _pairsList;

            public PrePairsList_IO()
            {
                _pairsList = new List<PrePair>();
            }

            public List<PrePair> PairsList { get => _pairsList; set => _pairsList = value; }

        }
```

Read/Write methods:

```
private void WriteList()
        {
            PrePairsList_IO prePairsList_IO = new PrePairsList_IO();
            List<PrePair> list = prePairsList_IO.PairsList;
            foreach (PrePair pair in pairs.Values)
            {
                list.Add(pair);
            }
            prePairsList_IO.PairsList = list;// Not sure this line required?

            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            Stream stream = new FileStream(_FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            formatter.Serialize(stream, prePairsList_IO);
            stream.Close();
        }

        private void ReadList()
        {
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            Stream stream = new FileStream(_filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            PrePairsList_IO prePairsList_IO = (PrePairsList_IO)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();

            List<PrePair> list = prePairsList_IO.PairsList;
            ListToDictionary(list);
        }
```

When I read in the data, my user functions work very fast. However, the process of reading in the file takes 4 minutes and I need to reduce that time dramatically.
What are my options to achieve this? I'm wondering if I can set up some persistant List variable or if there is a faster way to deserialize the data?
The precalculated data will never be changed so does not need to be written to at this point.
Thanks

Comment: _Not sure this line required?_ It is not. As for your problem, have you tried other serialization methods, like json, bson or xml?

Comment: No, this is the only approach I know. I'd really appreciate code examples for any suggestions.

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials on internet. Nowadays, json is the most used format for serialization, you can use the new [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0) or [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json). Json.NET also supports BSON.

Comment: well... what does `PrePair` look like?

Comment: Marc - PrePair contains 2 other custom objects. Since posting this question, I tried writing out the data in plain text instead of serialising. I found it much quicker (2 secs compared to 4 minutes) to read the text in line by line and recreate all my objects that way.